# Phonegap barcodescanner plugin crashes with "[CaptureBarcodesViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance"

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, barcode-scanner

when scanning barcode on ios I often get exception [CaptureBarcodesViewController respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance

xcode 5.1.1
ios 7.1.1
phonegap 3.1.0-0.15.0